# SSLError: ("bad handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate', 'certificate verify failed')])")))

Tags: certificate, python, single-sign-on

I want to scrape results from my company portal. It seems that my company intranet portal uses ping SSO to login.

So when I try to login, it is not asking for my username and password. When I go to the link https://portal.mycompany.com, it directs to https://ping-sso.mycompany.com/idp/... and then redirects to https://portal.mycompany.com

How do I login to the website using python and scrape results?

I tried to login directly using requests and I got the below error

```
r = requests.get("https://mycompanyintranetportal.com/home",
                 verify="C:/Users/me/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python37/webscraping/Lib/site-packages/certifi/cacert.pem")
```

> SSLError: HTTPSConnectionPool(host='mycompanyintranetportal.com', port=443):
> Max retries exceeded with url: /home (Caused by SSLError(SSLError("bad
> handshake: Error([('SSL routines', 'tls_process_server_certificate',
> 'certificate verify failed')])")))

One good thing  found is that I am able to access the ping SSO of mycompany portal.

```
requests.get("https://ping-mycompanyintranetportal.com/idp/ZGgWP/resumeSAML21/idp/SSO.ping")
```

Can someone help me with this please?

Comment: Is the url mycompanyinternetportal.com/home a valid URL?

Comment: That's a pure programming question, i.e. off-topic. And the error message `certificate verify failed`  says that the certificate given by the server is not trusted by the client - so your cacert.pem likely does not contain the (internal?) CA which issued the certificate of your intranet portal.

Comment: i mean i didnt want to put the real company portal here. Yeah its a valid one